# How to forecast time series from clusters?

Tags: time-series, clustering, forecasting, pooling

I have a set of 1200 time series for which I need to build a forecasting model. Since it is too time consuming to build a model for each series, I separated the series into clusters and what I want to do now is to build a forecasting model for each cluster (using time series techniques).

However, I don't know which is the best way to build that model for each cluster. Should I extract a series prototype and build the model on it? How do I do this?

In a paper by E. Maharaj (1999) (Forecasting Time Series From Clusters) the author forecasts time series from clusters by "pooling" the series together, but I can't understand how this pooling is done.

Answer (score 1):

Some software exists for "pooling time series". One of them is AUTOBOX, a piece of software that I have helped develop. If you have k time series then you can string them together one after the other. You can then elect to obtain a composite estimate of the model parameters. This composite estimate doesn't predict the first observation or any subsequent observation from the last (or prior) readings in the previous time series. One should then test to see of any of the series in the pool shouldn't be as its parameters are different from the "others".

Comment: @nick Send me your email address and I will forward you some material I have on the history of statistics.

Comment: @IrishStat do you know if there's any packet on R that allows mw to do something similar? And if I have, for instance, 400 series in one cluster, with 160 observations each, do you think this is to heavy to handle? Also, when fitting the forecast model, which frequency should I use? My observations are weekly data, therefore I have a frequency of 365.25/7, of 3 years and 4 weeks. Should exclude the 4 weeks?